# Flutter Grid with resizable & draggable items

Tags: flutter, resize, drag

How can I make Flutter widget that has different size items that each item can be resizable and draggable?
[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If0P9.png)

Answer (score 2):

There's a [StaggeredGridView package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) that does this on pub.dev

Comment: My attempts to do it with this library failed to make it resizeable or draggable. Do you have any instructions on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`flutter_staggered_grid_view`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package.

Comment: My attempts to do it with this library failed to make it resizeable or draggable. Do you have any instructions on how to do it?